# Excel 2016 VBA to Force Save and Close a separate Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, automation, excel-2016

My challenge: While I'm using a separate workbook to execute the VBA Code (Company will not allow most personnel to use a macro enabled workbook), some workbooks are being left open by users and the VBA can't save and close the refreshed workbook during automation.

I have been using this bit of code for years. I am wanting to refine the code to force save as and close open workbooks:

```vb
Sub RefreshUser1()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\General.local\shares\Shared\Dept\Tool\USERS\User1\Tool_User1.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I know there is something I'm missing to force an open workbook to SaveAs the same filename and Close, but just can't find it in my searches. Any and all help are truly appreciated!

Comment: Do a Google or Stack Overflow search for "automatically close open workbook if inactive"

Comment: To aid you in your search. You need to determine any open workbooks within the same Excel instance. Then run `.Close True` on each workbook. If they are in a separate Excel Instance, you'll need to find that instance and then loop the open workbooks in that instance and do the same.

Comment: Haven't been looking for "Inactive", but been working with using the .Close True, just not on each each workbook.Will update shortly with findings. Thank you kind folks!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to force a Save As and overwriting an existing instance of the workbook?

```
Sub RefreshUser1()
Dim Wb as Excel.Workbook

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\General.local\shares\Shared\Dept\Tool\USERS\User1\Tool_User1.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    WbName = Wb.path & "\" & Wb.name
    Wb.RefreshAll
    Wb.SaveAs (wb.name, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal)
    Wb.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```